# How to migrate MySql Database to Firestore

Tags: mysql, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm searching the best way to migrate my MySql database to Firebase's new Cloud Firestore. 
What are the steps? I'm trying first of all to convert my tables and relations in my relational db to a document logic.
I read about [Cloud Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) because I have more experience on using REST instead of socket, but I'm not sure if that's the point.
Is it a good idea to create a script starting from this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/master/firestore/test.firestore.js#L91-L101) and running it on nodeJS?
Has anyone already did this thing?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're wanting to jam relational data into a document store?  It can lead to incredible headaches down the road if you have too many relationships going on.

Comment: @dvsoukup it's a request from the customer, he would like to use Firebase instead of another service so it is necessary to study the migration process.

Comment: By far, the hardest part of this will be in designing the data model in order to allow for efficient querying and to apply rules effectively.  As @dvsoukup states, It's not an easy task.  If it's a particularly complex database and this is your first dabble with Cloud Firestore / NoSQL architecture, I'd suggest getting a specialist to work with you.  With regards to the actual library that you use to do it, Node.js would be my preferred option.

Comment: Let me save you a bunch of time; *there is no migration process*. SQL and NoSQL databases are radically different in how they store data and retrieve data. However, that doesn't mean it cannot be done! Here's where you start: determine very specifically, what you want to get out of your data; i.e you want to plot the next position Musk's Interplanetary Tesla based on prior coordinates and velocity. That output will then determine how you store the data in Firebase because the query you craft to get that data will be 100% different than if you wanted that same data from SQL. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh. I would suggest *starting small*. Pick one query you would run against your SQL to generate an output. Then work towards storing that data in Firebase with a structure. Craft a Firebase query to get said output. That will give you a much clearer understanding of the task at hand.

Comment: @Jay  I'm doing a sort of thing as you said, I'm creating a very small project starting from the core entities in my sql db and trying to create a good document/collection model and with that I'm trying to retrieve the data doing queries by tries. At the moment it works, but I guess there will be many problems soon. By the way thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a way to do that. But the way I suggest is using a programming language (python is preferable), make a script to turn all your data in the MySql database to a json format file structuring data in the way you want to store in Firestone. Then read the firestore API to populate instances in the documentary. This must work for sure!

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your mySQL database to a CSV file, and then convert that CSV to JSON.

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, it'd be preferable to show *how* this answers the question, i.e. add an example and a lot more explanation as to how this can be done. See [answer].